# Función con id en addEventListener

Tags: javascript

Necesito abrir la caja con cualquier botón, ya tengo el codigo pero no sé cómo añadirle la id de la caja en addEeventListener, ejemplo, openCity('caja')

¿que le añado para que cumpla su funcíon sin tener que cambiar todo el codigo?

```js
function openCity(cityName) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("city");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
}


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
  document.querySelectorAll('.look button').forEach((boton) => {
    boton.addEventListener('click', openCity); /* cómo puedo añadirle la id 'caja' openCity('caja')*/
  });
});
```

```css
.look{
padding: 15px;
background-color: #ddd;
text-align: center;
}
.city{
height: 100px;
background-color: #ff0;
display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="look">
<button>Open 1</button>
<button>Open 2</button>
<button>Open 3</button>
<button>Open 4</button>
<button>Open 5</button>
</div>

<div id="caja" class="city"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza un closure:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
  document.querySelectorAll('.look button').forEach((boton) => {
    boton.addEventListener('click', function(){ return openCity('caja'); }); /* cómo puedo añadirle la id 'caja' openCity('caja')*/
  });
});
```

Te dejo link para que puedas leer más al respecto: [Closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)